Dialog cutoff when adding offset to content
I was trying to make a re-sizable dialog that would also move when dragged. I noticed that beyond a certain point the dialog would be cutoff.

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.offset
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Dialog

@Composable
fun ResizableDialog(showDialog: Boolean, onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    if (showDialog) {
        var dialogWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(300.dp) }
        var dialogHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(200.dp) }
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(500f) } // if  starting at 0, then remember to move it up or down manually

        Dialog(onDismissRequest = onDismiss) {
            Surface(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                tonalElevation = 0.dp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.toInt(), offsetY.toInt()) }
                    .width(dialogWidth)
                    .height(dialogHeight)
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            // Move the dialog when dragging the entire surface
                            offsetX += dragAmount.x
                            offsetY += dragAmount.y
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
//                        .background(Color.Blue)
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Resizable Dialog")
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                        Button(onClick = onDismiss) {
                            Text("Close")
                        }
                    }


                }
            }

            // Add a draggable handle that extends beyond the top-left corner of the dialog
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(24.dp)
                    .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.toInt(), offsetY.toInt()) }
                    .offset(
                        x = (-12).dp,
                        y = (-12).dp
                    ) // Move the handle outside the dialog bounds
                    .background(Color.Gray)
//                    .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            // Resize the dialog when dragging the top-left corner handle
                            dialogWidth -= dragAmount.x.dp
                            dialogHeight -= dragAmount.y.dp
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ResizableDialogExample() {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Yellow),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { showDialog = true }) {
            Text("Show Resizable Dialog")
        }

        ResizableDialog(showDialog = showDialog, onDismiss = { showDialog = false })
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewResizableDialogExample() {
    ResizableDialogExample()
}

Why does this happen? When changing the width and height using the handle on the top left corner, there is no cutoff. I am not sure why a Dialog wouldn't be aware of the position/offset of its content.


Most probably, it could be because of the initial offsetY being 500f which is more than the intial height you applied for dialog!
